# How to use iteration in R to simplify my code for GLM?

Tags: r, loops, purrr, glm, simplify

I've just started using R and am having some issues when trying to simplify my code. I can't share my real data, but have used an open dataset to ask my question (Breed to represent my IV and Age to represent a DV).

In my dataset, I have all factor variables - my independent variable has 3 levels and my dependent variables all have 2 levels (0/1). Out of a larger dataset, I have six dependent variables and would like to run some descriptive stats and GLM for each. I have figured out working code for running each DV independently, see below. However, I am currently just copying & pasting this code and replacing the DV variables each time. I would like to instead create a function that I can apply to simplify my code.

I have attempted to do this using the purr package (map) but have had no luck. If someone could provide an example of how to do this using the sample data below, it would help me out a lot (though I know in the below data there is only one DV provided).

```
install.packages("GLMsData")
library(GLMsData)
data(butterfat)

library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
```

```
#Descriptive summaries
butterfat %>%
group_by(Breed, Age) %>%
summarise(n())

prop.table(table(butterfat$Breed, butterfat$Age), 1)

#Model
Age_model1 <- glm(Age ~ Breed, family=binomial, data=butterfat, na.action = na.omit)

#Get summary, including coefficients and p-values
summary(Age_model1)

#See coefficients, get odds ratio and confidence intervals
Age_model1$coefficients
exp(Age_model1$coefficients)
exp(confint(Age_model1))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Many Models: R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html)

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(lm = map(data,
                  ~glm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data = .))) %>% 
  mutate(tidy = map(lm,
                    broom::tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(tidy)
```